# HTTp 404 the resource your looking for (or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

hi i created new application in mvc2 asp and i run my application the following error are generate how to resolve this problem my url is **http://localhost:2620/asset/details/8**

**HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that there is no asset with the ID of 8.

What you need to do is either create an asset with the id of 8, or better still, show a meaningful message to the user.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //Assuming you are using the repository pattern
        Asset asset = assetRepository.GetAsset(id);

        if (asset == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        else
            return View(asset);
    }
```

After that create a view called 'NotFound' within the asset view directory, that tells the user a meaningful message

See the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)
Tutorials for lots of great assistance for people new to MVC2

Comment: public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //Assuming you are using the repository pattern
        Asset asset = assetRepository.GetAsset(id);

        if (asset == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        else
            return View(asset);
    } i write same code

Comment: id 1 to 20 assets in my database but problem is still plz help me

Comment: You'll need to post the code from your controller action in your question, otherwise i'm not sure how much i'll be able to help you